# python (sympy) implicit function: get values instead of plot?

Tags: python, plot, sympy, implicit

I am new to sympy but I already get a nice output when I plot the implicit function (actually the formula for [Cassini's ovals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval)) using sympy:

```
from sympy import plot_implicit, symbols, Eq, solve
x, y = symbols('x y')
k=2.7
a=3
eq = Eq((x**2 + y**2)**2-2*a**2*(x**2-y**2), k**4-a**4)
plot_implicit(eq)
```

Now is it actually possible to somehow get the **x** and **y** values corresponding to the plot? or alternatively solve the implicit equation without plotting at all?

thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an answer addressing your

> is it actually possible to somehow get the x and y values corresponding to the plot?

and I say *"addressing"* because it's not possible to get the `x` and `y` values  used to draw the curves — because the curves are not drawn using a sequenc of 2D points… more on this later,

---

**TL;DR**

```
pli = plot_implicit(...)
series = pli[0]
data, action = series.get_points()
data = np.array([(x_int.mid, y_int.mid) for x_int, y_int in data])
```

---

Let's start with your code

```
from sympy import plot_implicit, symbols, Eq, solve
x, y = symbols('x y')
k=2.7
a=3
eq = Eq((x**2 + y**2)**2-2*a**2*(x**2-y**2), k**4-a**4)
```

and plot it, with a twist: we save the `Plot` object and print it

```
pli = plot_implicit(eq)
print(pli)
```

to get

```
Plot object containing:
[0]: Implicit equation: Eq(-18*x**2 + 18*y**2 + (x**2 + y**2)**2, -27.8559000000000) for x over (-5.0, 5.0) and y over (-5.0, 5.0)
```

We are interested in this object indexed by `0`,

```
ob = pli[0]
print(dir(ob))
```

that gives (ellipsis are mine)

```
['__class__', …, get_points, …, 'var_y']
```

The name `get_points` sounds full of promise, doesn't it?

```
 print(ob.get_points())
```

that gives (edited for clarity and with a big cut)

```
([
  [interval(-3.759774, -3.750008), interval(-0.791016, -0.781250)],
  [interval(-3.876961, -3.867195), interval(-0.634768, -0.625003)],
  [interval(-3.837898, -3.828133), interval(-0.693361, -0.683596)],
  [interval(-3.847664, -3.837898), interval(-0.673830, -0.664065)],
  ...
  [interval(3.837895, 3.847661), interval(0.664064, 0.673830)],
  [interval(3.828130, 3.837895), interval(0.683596, 0.693362)],
  [interval(3.867192, 3.876958), interval(0.625001, 0.634766)],
  [interval(3.750005, 3.759770), interval(0.781255, 0.791021)]
  ], 'fill')
```

What is this? the documentation of `plot_implicit` has

> `plot_implicit`, by default, uses [interval arithmetic to plot functions](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~mooncake/papers/SIGGRAPH2001_Tupper.pdf).

Following the source code of `plot_implicit.py` and `plot,py` one realizes that, in this case, the actual plotting (speaking of the `matpolotlib` backend) is just a line of code

```
 self.ax.fill(x, y, facecolor=s.line_color, edgecolor='None')
```

where `x` and `y` are constructed from the list of intervals, as returned from `.get_points()`, as follows

```
x, y = [], []
for intervals in interval_list:
    intervalx = intervals[0]
    intervaly = intervals[1]
    x.extend([intervalx.start, intervalx.start,
                  intervalx.end, intervalx.end, None])
    y.extend([intervaly.start, intervaly.end,
                  intervaly.end, intervaly.start, None])
```

so that for each couple of intervals `matplotlib` is directed to draw a filled rectangle, small enough that the eye sees a continuous line (note the use of `None` to have disjoint rectangles).

We can conclude that the list of couples of intervals

```
l_xy_intervals = ((pli[0]).get_points())[0]
```

represents rectangular areas where the implicit expression you are plotting is
*"true enough"*

Comment: Forgot to mention, the interval couples in the big list, being produced by an adaptive procedure, are not guaranteed to come out in any particular order,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, even with interval math, if you try getting the mid point of each interval. Starting from your code, and slightly change it, by saving the `plot_implicit` object in a variable called `g` we have:

```
from sympy import plot_implicit, symbols, Eq, solve
x, y = symbols('x y')
k=2.7
a=3
eq = Eq((x**2 + y**2)**2-2*a**2*(x**2-y**2), k**4-a**4)
g = plot_implicit(eq)
```

Now let's save in a variable named `ptos` the intervals that were used to draw the plot.

```
ptos = g[0].get_points()[0]
```

This way `ptos[0][0]` will be the first interval in the x axis and `ptos[0][1]` will be its pair in the y axis. The intervals have a property called `mid` which gives the middle point of the interval. So you can suppose that `ptos[0][0].mid, ptos[0][1].mid` will be a pair `x,y` "true enough" to be one of our numerical solutions.

This way, a data frame composed of this middle point pairs can be generated with:

```
intervs = np.array(dtype='object')
meio = lambda x0:x0.mid
px = list(map(meio, intervs[:,0]))
py = list(map(meio, intervs[:,1]))  
import pandas as pd
dados = pd.DataFrame({'x':px, 'y':px})
dados.head()
```

Which in this example would give us:

```
           x         y
 0 -1.177733  0.598826
 1 -1.175389  0.596483
 2 -1.175389  0.598826
 3 -1.173045  0.596483
 4 -1.173045  0.598826
```

This idea of getting the intervals middle points can be used whenever one needs to move from "interval math" to "standard" point level math. Hope this helps. Regards.